Unique reconstruction of rubik's cube state from images
Suppose I have 6 images of a rubik's cube. Each representing one face. The orientation of each image is arbitrary. Given that the images are from a valid cube state can I always reconstruct the rubik's cube state. Is there only one unique solution? Thanks.
Edit: For a solved state the possible combinations are 4^6. However they all result in the same cube state. The combinations don't really matter, I am interested in the number of unique cube states.

For a solved Rubik's cube, it is impossible to tell which way around the images are, so there are $4^6$ different ways to stitch them together. On the other hand, you get the same cube no matter which way you choose.

No there won't be a uniwue solution everytime. Take counter case
$$\begin{matrix}
 & \begin{bmatrix}
Y & W & Y \\
Y & Y & Y \\
Y & W & Y
\end{bmatrix} & & \\
\begin{bmatrix}
G & G & G \\
G & G & G \\
G & G & G
\end{bmatrix} & \begin{bmatrix}
O & O & O \\
O & O & O \\
O & O & O
\end{bmatrix} & \begin{bmatrix}
B & B & B \\
B & B & B \\
B & B & B
\end{bmatrix} & \begin{bmatrix}
R & R & R \\
R & R & R \\
R & R & R
\end{bmatrix} \\
 & \begin{bmatrix}
W & Y & W \\
W & W & W \\
W & Y & W
\end{bmatrix} & & \\
\end{matrix}$$
You can rotate the $Y$ and $W$ faces here by $90^\circ$ which is also a solution for an actual rubik's cube.
An algorithm to find all possible solutions is to go over all $4^6$ possible orientations and check:

All corners are valid, and exhaustive
All edges are valid, and exhaustive
If you take the permutation cycles of edges and corners (considering only position), the total parity is not odd.
Edge orientation parity is not odd.
Total corner orientation is divisible by $3$

Finally remove all solutions which are equivalent under whole cube orientation.

I don't seem to understand what you mean by rotate 90 degrees


The orientation of each image is arbitrary. Doesn't this mean that I can rotate any face to get to another solution


You do know that the face does not rotate independently right. rotating one face also affects the adject edges and corners and would lead to a totally different cube state. That's why I don't understand what you meant by rotate 90 degrees.

Yeah I understand that, I do not mean rotate as in rotating an actual cube. I mean rotate before even making the cube. Consider you are given the 6 images as above and you have to stitch them together to form a valid cube. Then I can form 2 possible cubes with the above 6 faces (one where $WO \leftrightarrow YO, WR \leftrightarrow YR$ and one where $WB \leftrightarrow YB, WG \leftrightarrow YG$)

This is a great counter example.  My understanding of the question is that, say you took a scramble of a valid cube, took each of its sides, and made six 3x3 squares out of those sides.  Can you tape those squares back into a cube a different way, and have that configuration be a valid scramble?  @EnEm's example means the answer to this question is yes.  In his answer, take the Y and W sides (just the 3x3 square of colors), rotate BOTH 90 degrees (either left or right, doesn't matter, as it's symmetric).  What you're left with is a valid scramble that is different than the original.

@brayo They meant "you can rotate the images of the $Y$ and $W$ faces $90^\circ$, and still be able to stitch it into a solvable cube."

Thanks, everyone. I now understand. Not to be a bother but is there also an upperbound on the number of solutions available?

Generally, with a Rubik'sCube, you know that colours $C_1$ and $C_4$ are opposite, $C_2$ and $C_5$ are opposite, and when you have $C_1$ in front, $C_2$ in top, you know whether $C_3$ is on left or on right. If you know those informations, the answer is probably totally different.

@Lourrran Thats a good point. I assumed inherently that we are using the BOY color scheme : https://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/japanese-western-color-schemes/

@brayo I think an upper bound would be $\frac{2^{10}}{3}$ because of the checks I mentioned. You can get better practical upperbounds by simulating the above for a large number of random cube states.
